# Alignment/projection issue when opening a shapefile in ArcMap that was sourced from XML file

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, error, xml, route

I seek to build a UK bus route in ArcMap and am currently  attempting to utilise an .xml file sourced from gov.uk.

I have had some difficulty in converting the .xml file into a shapefile.

So far, I have tried converting the .xml file into a CSV file, adding the X Y coordinates (lat, long) to ArcMap to create a point shapefile. The new shapefile layer was then exported. I added the exported shapefile back into the map and defined its Geographic and Projected coordinate systems and then used the 'Project' tool to attempt to align it with my basemap. These are:

> Projected Coordinate System:   British_National_Grid
> Projection: Transverse_Mercator
> False_Easting:  400000.00000000
> False_Northing: -100000.00000000
> Central_Meridian:   -2.00000000
> Scale_Factor:   0.99960127
> Latitude_Of_Origin: 49.00000000
> Linear Unit:    Meter

> Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_OSGB_1936
> Datum:  D_OSGB_1936
> Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
> Angular Unit:   Degree

[image: Misaligned bus stop data to the main road]

These tools failed to align the shapefile and, despite further attempts to ensure the shapefile shares the desired projected and geographic coordinate systems (manual input via ArcCatalog -> Properties -> XY Coordinate System -> New), this shapefile still fails to align with the map.

Can anyone provide any advice on this process? I am new to using .xml files, coordinate systems and GIS in general.

The .XML file can be downloaded from:
https://data.bus-data.dft.gov.uk/category/dataset/152/
I am focusing on the number '46' bus route, which data is included in the **JE_46_NMS_PB_46_20200330** .xml file.

Comment: Are you sure the GCS is GCS_OSGB_1936?  I just did a quick search for TransXchange coordinate system and a UK [FAQ](http://naptan.dft.gov.uk/transxchange/technicalFaq.htm#PubCoords) says they are WGS84 if provided as lon/lats.

Comment: @user2856 Thank you for your comment. You helped me realise that my problem lied with the lons/lats coordinates being incompatible with the BNG. I converted the lon/lats data into Eastings and Northings, added it to the map as XY data and projected it, which solved the problem.